# What is NoOp in TensorFlow when Profiling?

Tags: python, tensorflow, profiling, gpu, no-op

I'm profiling ops on a GPU. What is going on behind the long NoOp?

It seems like NoOp might represent the time between transferring data from GPU to CPU, since the final operation, TopKV2, executes on the CPU (does not have a GPU kernel) in TF 0.11.0.

[image]

Comment: Were you able to figure out the answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely sure but it seems to be related to some initialization mechanism for the placeholder node in the graph.

[No-op description from Tensorflow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/cc/class/tensorflow/ops/no-op)

Comment: From the document, the NoOp is used as the placeholder for "control edges", which is the way to control the order of nodes that have not input/output relation between each other. Therefore, I think NoOp is used to control the execution order of the nodes rather than initialization mechanism for the placeholder.